# Readonly role c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a customroleprovider.cs
I have a user table that has users and their roles. most users have role as user, there are only 3 admin, now i need to create 3 readonly users. these users can only view the whole website, and cannot edit any part of the website. in my views i have these:

```
 @{
        var simpleRoles = (RoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
    }
    @if (simpleRoles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "admin"))
    {
}
```

to restrict some areas only for admin, do i need something like this for readonly users?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have admin and users, you may want to create an "admin" area and a "user" area.  What I suggested below is only if you have a few views you want to hide from roles.  In the admin area you can add the authorize attribute to a base controller for that area so that only admins can update content.  Otherwise, you'll have to have if statements in the views if you wanted to hide the update buttons from different appearing for roles, and that could get messy.

UPDATE:

Below is a link for an overview of areas.  Areas are nice because you can create an area called "Admin" and inside that area you will have controllers/views/viewmodels, etc... that are separate from a different area.  Inside this area you can include the logic for updating content, whereas if you don't want a role to update content then don't include the logic inside their area.  Hopefully the link will do a better job explaining it than I can.

When I use areas for my project, I'll create a base controller that all of my controllers inherit from.  An example of what my base controller may look like is:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class AdminBaseController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Then in all of my controllers in the area I'll inherit from the AdminBaseController so that only admins can access this section of the website.

```
public class HomeController : AdminBaseController
{
    ...
}
```

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/a9P1010113-MVC-Areas-with-example.html

Adding an Authorize attribute on the view:

For example, if you only want admin's to view the view.cshtml file then you can do something like this on the controller action:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult View() 
{
    ....
}
```

If user's aren't in that role then they will be be able to access that view.

For multiple roles, you can do:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin, user")]
public ActionResult View()
{
    ...
}
```

This will allow anybody that is an admin OR user to view the page.  (They don't have to be in both roles).

Comment: can i add multiple roles? admin, and user?

Comment: Yes it should be [Authorize(Roles="admin, user")].  Actually, let me look up the syntax to double check the correct way.

Comment: Auth attribute is way to go as above. But does not solve the issue of  'read-only'. You will need to ad some logic evaluate the user's role then return a different view -- dirty example: if (!Roles.IsUsersInRole("readonly")) { return View("Details", model); }

Comment: I misread the question the first time.  I edited my answer to suggest areas.

Comment: @gnome i agree about the logic as when i added the authorize it didn't work. it even didn't allow me as an admin to edit

Comment: I would point out that using `@if(){}` in your view to hide buttons does **NOT** protect you from someone sending the post data to your controller and causing the action to execute; security must be implemented at the controller level.

Comment: @Menew have you used areas before?  I think that is the way to go.

Comment: I'll update my answer hopefully in a couple minutes.  I'm trying to look for a good website that can explain it better and give you a brief walk through of it.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on my comment above. Decorating your controller actions with the Authorization Attribute will lock down it to the specific role(s). This does not solve the issue of a read-only type role. You will need some logic in the controller action to evaluate the role then return a different view. I recommend placing this in a BaseController. Have your other controllers inherit it:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        this.IsReadOnly = Roles.IsUserInRole("readonly");
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin, user, readonly")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        if (!IsReadOnly)
        {
            return View("Details");
        }
        ... other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have an authorizeadmin controller so i will add these to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in .cshtml

`@if ( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ){
    if ( User.IsInRole("Admin") ){
        @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminController")

    }
}`